# Why is my toString() not working as I wanted?

Tags: java

> The toString() method will return a String that includes all of the
> items in the purchases array, organized by category.

This is my output that I got wrong:

```
OTHER GROCERY ITEMS:
Flour     $1.89     2    $3.78

OTHER GROCERY ITEMS:
Slaw $3.73     4    $14.92   Perishable
```

But instead it should look something like this:

```
OTHER GROCERY ITEMS:
Flour     $1.89     2    $3.78
Slaw $3.73     4    $14.92   Perishable
```

That is, the header for a category of items should appear only once.

Here is my code:

```
public class GrocItem extends Item{
    
    private boolean perishable;
    
    public GrocItem(String name, double price, int qty,boolean perishable) {
        super(name, price, qty);
        this.perishable = perishable;
        perishable = false;
        
    }
    
    public boolean isPerishable() {
        return perishable;
        
    }
    
    public void setPerishable(boolean perishable) {
        this.perishable = perishable;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(isPerishable()){
             return "\nOTHER GROCERY ITEMS:\n" + super.getName() + "\t" + "$"+getPrice() + "\t" + getQty() +"\t"+"$"+getPrice()*getQty() +"\t"+ "Perishable";
            }
         else{
                return "\nOTHER GROCERY ITEMS:\n"+super.getName() + "\t" + "$"+getPrice() + "\t" + getQty()+"\t"+"$"+getPrice()*getQty() ;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: If the header should not appear once per item then it should not be in the `toString` method of the item class at all. It sounds like you need to write this method on a different class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't print the header in `GrocItem#toString`. Print it once before the loop over the items.

```
System.out.println("OTHER GROCERY ITEMS:");
```

You don't want to use `\n` in `toString` either - avoid writing contextual things there. Today it's a table, tomorrow it could be a one-line comma separated list.

The method could be simplified a little:

```
public String toString() {
  return super.getName() + "\t" + "$" + getPrice() + "\t" + getQty() + "\t" + "$" + getPrice() * getQty() + (isPerishable() ? "\tPerishable" : "");
}
```

Notice that now only a small bit `(isPerishable() ? "\tPerishable" : "")` is conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the tester class, so I'll make some assumptions. So,
I'm assuming you have an array or arraylist of grocery items that you're looping through and printing.

When you print each grocery item, each grocery items returns the "\nOTHER GROCERY ITEM:\n" part at the beginning. So it'll print that each time.

To fix this, just get rid of that part so it's just `return super.name() + ... + ... ;`.
Then, print the header before the loop.

Example

```
System.out.println("\nOTHER GROCERY ITEM:");
for (GrocItem g : yourArray) {
    System.out.println(g)
}
```